# Chrome 67 and Dojo

Tags: dojo

1.Which version of dojo works fine with chrome 67 or other higher versions? 
2. Recently after the chrome upgrade- dojo.js does not loads and throws following error-

```
dojo.js:15 Error: multipleDefine
    at _f (dojo.js:15)
    at _f3 (dojo.js:15)
    at def (dojo.js:15)
    at dojo_en-us.js:1
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
_9 @ dojo.js:15
req.signal @ dojo.js:15
_f3 @ dojo.js:15
def @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ dojo_en-us.js:1
dojo.js:15 Error: multipleDefine
    at _f (dojo.js:15)
    at _f3 (dojo.js:15)
    at def (dojo.js:15)
    at Grid.js.uncompressed.js:11
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
_9 @ dojo.js:15
req.signal @ dojo.js:15
_f3 @ dojo.js:15
def @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ Grid.js.uncompressed.js:11
dojo.js:15 Error: multipleDefine
    at _f (dojo.js:15)
    at _f3 (dojo.js:15)
    at def (dojo.js:15)
    at OnDemandList.js.uncompressed.js:70
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
_9 @ dojo.js:15
req.signal @ dojo.js:15
_f3 @ dojo.js:15
def @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ OnDemandList.js.uncompressed.js:70
dojo.js:15 Error: multipleDefine
    at _f (dojo.js:15)
    at _f3 (dojo.js:15)
    at def (dojo.js:15)
    at List.js.uncompressed.js:51
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:15
_9 @ dojo.js:15
req.signal @ dojo.js:15
_f3 @ dojo.js:15
def @ dojo.js:15
(anonymous) @ List.js.uncompressed.js:51
VM185:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: normal is not defined
    at eval (eval at f (css.js.uncompressed.js:1), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at f (css.js.uncompressed.js:1)
   at Object.load (css.js.uncompressed.js:1)
    at _e4 (dojo.js:15)
    at dojo.js:15
    at _9 (dojo.js:15)
    at _ce (dojo.js:15)
    at _35 (dojo.js:15)
    at _36 (dojo.js:15)
    at dojo.js:15
```

3. We are using dojo version 1.9.1

Could anyone please suggest about this?

It was working perfectly fine with previous versions of Chrome browser and we do not see any such error in IE browser for same version of dojo.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, show your code.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** From my point of view 1.9 should work. I use latest in my project, but tried some basic things in [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejmbdts4/) and got no problems. My chrome version is 67.

**2.** Just and idea where to look... As far as I can see, this error can happen in case when you have multiple define functions in one file (module). At least I tried this and got same error.

```
            if(module.injected === arrived){
                signal(error, makeError("multipleDefine", module));
                return module;
            }
```

This code is from dojo.js
You could place a breakpoint there and check what's wrong with module.